# I was scanning my local network for ports and found 5001 tcp/commplex-link. What is it?

Tags: networking, router, nmap

Apparently my home router is listening on port 5001:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.018s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
5001/tcp  open  commplex-link
52869/tcp open  unknown
```

I tried googleing for port number (5001) and protocol (commplex-link) but couldn't find any clarification.

Does any body know what is that protocol or if it exists as a standard? Link to documentation would be nice.

Comment: What sort of router it is would help - also while its a well known port, ports are not always used for the registered protocol... so it might not actually be "commplex-link"

Comment: I agree, and thus I don't think it matters which router it is. I just want more info on the protocol itself. If nmap catched it I think it cannot be so "unknown". Nevertheless I couldn't find it.

Comment: It matters here simply because someone else might have come across it - alternative fun stuff to do is try using telnet and seeing what the response is... but if its something 'unique' to that router, it would narrow it down.

Comment: for example - wikipedia suggests [slingbox/slingplayer and synology use it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Answer (score 1):

That port is likely bound by "iperf" running on your router. iperf is used to test data throughput between two devices. If you get iperf on a computer connected to your router, you can verify this by running

`iperf -c 192.168.1.1`

5001 is the default port used by iperf.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf